# Grunt Image Paths in CoffeeScript (eco) Templates

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, yeoman, eco

I've ran into a slight issue referring to images in production environment. Image files are generated using imagemin and I end up with /images/.. files – which is totally fine, but I don't know how to refer to them in CoffeeScript. Specifically in my ECO templates that I'm using BackboneJS with.

Everything works fine in CSS – compass seems to be taking care of putting in the right urls. But there's no helper I can use (or I don't know how) to refer to that image url.

So a simple:

```
<img src="images/draggable.png" />
```

Works in development, but not in production.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using grunt/yeoman. Here's my Gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
  var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
  var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({port: LIVERELOAD_PORT});
  var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
      return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
  };
}

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'
// templateFramework: 'lodash'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        watch: {
            options: {
                nospawn: true,
                livereload: true
            },
            coffeeTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:test']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}'
                ]
            },
            eco: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates/**/*.eco',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}'
                ],
                tasks: ['eco', 'coffee:dist', 'neuter']
            },
            jst: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates/*.ejs'
                ],
                tasks: ['jst']
            },
            neuter: {
                files: ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/**/*.{js,coffee}'],
                tasks: ['coffee:dist', 'neuter']
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            lrSnippet,
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'test'),
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        open: {
            server: {
                path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: ['.tmp', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*'],
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },
        coffee: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    // rather than compiling multiple files here you should
                    // require them into your main .coffee file
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                    src: '**/*.coffee',
                    dest: '.tmp/scripts',
                    ext: '.js'
                }]
            },
            test: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/spec',
                    src: '*.coffee',
                    dest: 'test/spec'
                }]
            }
        },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                relativeAssets: true
            },
            dist: {},
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                        '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                    //collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    src: '*.html',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        bower: {
            all: {
                rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js'
            }
        },
        eco: {
          compile: {
              files: {
                  '.tmp/scripts/templates.js': ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates/{,*/}*.eco']
              }
          }
        },
        jst: {
            compile: {
                files: {
                    '.tmp/scripts/templates.js': ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/templates/*.ejs']
                }
            }
        },
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        neuter: {
            app: {
                src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js',
                dest: '.tmp/scripts/combined-scripts.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('createDefaultTemplate', function () {
        grunt.file.write('.tmp/scripts/templates.js', 'this.JST = this.JST || {};');
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'coffee:dist',
            'createDefaultTemplate',
            'eco',
            'neuter:app',
            'compass:server',
            'connect:livereload',
            'open',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'coffee',
        'createDefaultTemplate',
        'eco',
        'neuter:app',
        'compass',
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'coffee',
        'createDefaultTemplate',
        'eco',
        'compass:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'neuter:app',
        'imagemin',
        'htmlmin',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('heroku', 'build');


};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site is served from the root of your host: domain.com, then you could use absolute urls to fix this: src="/images/image.png". If not, you might have to figure out where they are.

Actually, the problem is probably the grunt-rev task. It renames the images and updates the CSS/HTML but probably isnt doing it in your templates. You could either check the plugin to see if it supports that task and if it doesn't, patch it so it does or not have images in the templates and maybe have them in CSS only as background images.

Comment: Yup – it was grunt-rev and I went with the CSS only approach since I was trying to move fast. I should probably see if I rev supports eco templates next :)

Comment: Seeing the same issue with Angular HTML views. I was really hoping that rev could handle this.

Comment: @Swaraj you really shouldnt serving the html views in angular. optimally you should store them in the template cache so no extra ajax request is needed. Yeoman's Angular generator doesn't do this yet but will in the next release (a new release is coming out today).

Comment: What do you mean I shouldn't server HTML views in angular. In my project I have many directives which link to their own HTML template (via templateURL). I include these directives in my main view, and each HTML template is loaded separately.

Comment: I mean you should use templateCache and convert the raw html files into JS strings and cache the one js file instead

Comment: I think that rev is trying to force us to use background-image, rather than img. Not a bad practice, but a bit of a shock when everything breaks.